# openssl -in and/or -certfile?

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, x509certificate, tls1.3

I generate TLS cert in Ubuntu using the following commands:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -nodes -days 365 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj "/C=SG/ST=Singapore/L=Singapore /O=My Company Pte. Ltd./OU=My Organization/CN=localhost/emailAddress=a@b.c"
openssl pkcs12 -export -out twocerts.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt -certfile server.crt -passout pass:mypass
```

What's the diff between `-in` and `-certfile`? Are they redundant of each other? It hangs when I use `-certfile` ONLY without `-in`:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out /tmp/localhost.pfx -inkey server.key -certfile server.crt -passout pass:mypass
```

What's the use case of using both in the same command?

How to run these commands in Windows 11?

Comment: This is not programming or development, and is explained on the man page in the section "PKCS12 output (export) options". (For native Windows i.e. not WSL, which doesn't have man pages, see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html#PKCS-12-output-export-options). _For additional aka extra cert(s) NOT matching the key_ you can use either `-in`/stdin or `-certfile`; this is/these are useful only if it is/they are relevant CA cert(s) which your self-signed cert case doesn't have.

Comment: It hangs when I use `-certfile` only without `-in`. What's the use case of using both options in the same command?

Comment: If you don't use `-in` and don't redirect or pipe stdin, then it reads from the terminal and you must manually type a cert, thousands of characters, perfectly, terminated by control-D on Unix or control-Z and return on Windows. Humans can't do that. So either use `-in` or redirect or pipe from something that contains the cert and optionally the key as the man page says. Use `-certfile` if and only if you want to supply additional/extra (CA) cert(s) not in `-in`/stdin; in _your_ specific case, there is(are) no such cert(s).